# Customize option of admin nav bar in wordpress website showing 403 forbidden error in server

Tags: wordpress

I have hosted my wordpress site in Bigrock.In the home page  of the site after logged in as admin,in the admin nav bar when I click the cutomize option it is it showing 403 forbidden error,but the same works perfect in localhost.How to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Check Your htaccess file

Comment: this is my htacces file.  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /iys/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /iys/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
Update this And try

Comment: Tried.No change.

Comment: try to check with permalink default option

Comment: Tried this also..But no change